# Google Chrome app update - Don't play html webview video

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, webview

I am developing an app with a webview. The webview contains some HTML videos. The video is working fine before the update of the Google Chrome app but after I updated my chrome app to Chrome 73.0.3683.90(latest update), the video on the webview can't be played. Any solution for this?

```
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```